# I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application hosted in AWS. in this users will load files. Where to save these files

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application hosted in AWS. in this users will load files. Where to save these files? Do I need to load to s3 or create a new EC2 and save files inside or efx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely upload the file to S3. It's meant to store files.

You can for example use AWS SDK from your backend to upload the file received by the front to S3: [Upload an Object Using the AWS SDK for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpNET.html)

Or the backend could send a presigned URL to the frontend so that the upload is done directly by the frontend application: [Uploading Objects Using Presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for the answer. what is the best industry practice ?

Comment: Well it depends on your use case. In our case, we upload the file through an API endpoint which streams the files directly to S3 because we do some processing on the files. But we mainly store PDFs and we don't have tons of them so bandwith is not really an issue. It's also quite straightforward. If you plan on uploading media/heavy files, you should go for option 2 though.

Comment: i was trying to load the file. but it is allowing me only if i un-check "Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)" in s3. else i am getting access denied.